# how to save data to sql from extra input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Hey im new on laravel and php but i have problem at my project, everything is great but when i want to save data from a form called 'jurusan' it won't saved to sql. here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tingkat Pendidikan :</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tingkatPendidikan" id="selector">
        <option value="SD">SD</option>
        <option value="SMP">SMP</option>
        <option value="SMA">SMA</option>
        <option value="SMK">SMK</option>
        <option value="universitas">Universtias</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="SMA op" style="display:none">
    <label>Jurusan</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="jurusan">
        <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
        <option value="IPS">IPS</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="SMK op" style="display:none">
    <label>Jurusan</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="masukan jenis jurusan " name="jurusan" >
</div>
<div class="universitas op" style="display:none">
    <label>Fakultas</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="masukan jenis fakultas " name="jurusan" >
</div>
```

then this script i use to show 'jurusan' form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selector').on('change',function() {
        var divClass = $(this).val();
        $(".op").hide();
        $("."+divClass).slideDown('medium');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, you have two `<input tyep="text"/>` with name `jurusan`, this is the problem, either you have different name or you can `enable/disable` input type when you hide/show the `div` container.

Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selector').on('change',function() {
        var divClass = $(this).val();
        $(".op").hide();
        $(".op :text").prop("disabled", true);
        $("."+divClass).slideDown('medium');
        $("."+ divClass + " :text").prop("disabled", false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @RizaSetiawan, please accept my answer if it solve your issue. Thanks :)